# Rails 5 JSON API with custom JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm battling with my JSON rendering. I want to comply with the simple [JSend response format](https://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend/wiki).

Basically what I want is the status and the data in my response.

I've set up my Serializer default adapter to json :

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json
```

My serializer is simple :

```
class RecordSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :raw
end
```

So when I do this :

```
record_list = @current_user.records
render json: record_list
```

I got this :

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "raw": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "raw": "bbb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now the tricky part, if I want to add a *data* key on top, it override my *records* key instead of adding it on top.

```
render json: record_list, root: "data"
```

Give this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "raw": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "raw": "bbb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, how can I add other keys like the *status* key ? As soon as I create a custom Hash, the serializer is ignored. So for example this :

```
render json: {:status=>"success", :code=>200, :message=>"Hello", data: record_list}
```

Will returns this :

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Hello",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "raw": "aaa",
            "created_at": "2018-07-16T19:49:32.960Z",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-16T19:49:32.960Z",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "raw": "bbb",
            "created_at": "2018-07-16T20:01:55.804Z",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-16T20:01:55.804Z",
        }
    ]
}
```

---

So I think I understand that `render json: my_variable` alone will understand to transform `my_variable` into the choosen json serializer adapter but cannot with a custom Hash ?

Of course I could do this :

```
record_list = {}
record_list["records"] = @current_user.records.select(:id, :raw)
```

But I feel like this is not the right way and then the Serializer would be useless.

**Thanks !**

Comment: have you thought about opting out of serializers and using [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) instead?

Comment: you might want to look into json:api and graphQL which both have gems that will set you up with generated serializers that work almost out of the box and provide a lot more structure and functionality than jsend

Comment: @robertoplancarte JSON API and graphQL seems heavy for my usage so this is why I wanted something light.

Comment: @andrew21 I will look at it but this seems to bypass the issue and not really solve it. Thanks anyway for the suggestion

Comment: For my Rails-based API application I initially started with [representable](https://github.com/trailblazer/representable) for generating JSON responses but   as my JSON templates grown it didn't provided a clean approach to reuse already defined representations and thus I switched to used [rabl-rails](https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails) and since then I am successfully and satisfactorily using it for generating JSON responses. (contd in next comment)

Comment: Next when Rails 5 was released [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) gem was made part of [Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19832). And I evaluated Rails API serializers but it didn't turned out to be the solution to replace 3rd party gems for JSON templating in my application. As part of that evaluation I also created a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34001012/936494) reporting the problem I was facing but I didn't received any responses. Thus I decided to stick to rabl-rails and I am continuing using it without any issues and I would suggest you to try it too.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your experience @JiggneshhGohel
If I don't find a "better" solution, I think I will consider going for rails-api even if it's overkill for my usage for now or for rabl-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've chosen to give it a try to the [Fast JSON API gem](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) from the Netflix team. Great customisation possible, fast and lightweight.

Comment: pls be noted - As of today, its not maintained.